# IOS - can't load image at root of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm new to iOS and need to create a NSURL that points to an image that I have copied into the root of my application (i.e. same directory as the AppDelegate & my controller class files reside).

Giving the following code, why does the image not load & how can I get the if condition to validate (i.e. have a `NSURL` reference to my image)?

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *image2AbsolutPath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSURL *urlToImage = [NSURL URLWithString:image2AbsolutPath];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![urlToImage checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"image2.jpg could not be reached.");
}
```

Edit: As per the comment; created an imageview and successfully loaded and viewed the image via; `self.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"];`

Only the `NSURL` loading seems to not work.

Comment: Have you added the image2.jpg to the project? (And not just to the file system folder)

Comment: If you did it and still not working. Have you added the image2.jpg to your current target?.

Comment: If the image is in your project you should just be able to load the image like this, `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];` I say this because you have stated that you put it with your files such as AppDelegate etc.

Comment: use this [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"]; and also check spelling of ur image name.

Comment: why do you want to get a NSURL to the image within your project?

Comment: @user3752753 - for the AWS S3 Transfer Manager

Comment: @Undeph Via XCode and dragged into the app which appears.

Comment: @Ian try `NSURL *MyURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"image2" withExtension:@"jpg"];`

Comment: @sbarow That worked, thanks - if you could add it as the answer and any theory of why it doesn't work with my code then that would be great & I will accept..

Comment: @lan I did add both ;) simple typo

Comment: try with `PNG` as long as the `JPG` is not really supported in bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the resource you need to use

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"image2" withExtension:@"jpg"];
```

If you look at the two different paths created with `pathForResource` vs the `URLForResource` method you will see the `NSURL` path is missing the required `file://`

```
pathForResource:

/Users/MacbookPro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02D50AC9-5AF0-4F23-8757-1AF7D3153344/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C5775786-E473-4048-9855-A2C6AA51BB05/MyApp.app/image2.png
```

vs

```
URLForResource:

file:///Users/MacbookPro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/02D50AC9-5AF0-4F23-8757-1AF7D3153344/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C5775786-E473-4048-9855-A2C6AA51BB05/MyApp.app/image2.png
```

Comment: I didn't vote as I was told not to do it when I participate but this doesn't answer why the OPs code doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 3):

you mixup `URLWithString` and `fileURLWithPath`

```
//wrong
NSString *image2AbsolutPath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSURL *urlToImage = [NSURL URLWithString:image2AbsolutPath];
```

you use the former but pass it NOT a url string BUT a file path. Change to the latter and it would work

```
//works
NSString *image2AbsolutPath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSURL *urlToImage = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:image2AbsolutPath];
```

---

```
//but more simply
NSURL *urlToImage = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"image2" withExtension:@"jpg"];
```